# ArcSDE/ST_Geometry: Can I store polygon and point geometries in same row?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, well-known-text, st-geometry

In the system I'm building, we've got a facility that can be represented as either a point, or a point within a polygon (the point in the polygon may or may not be the polygon's centroid).

I'm using Oracle/ArcSDE with the ST_Geometry storage type. Is it possible to store both point and polygon data for a single feature? Or does each require its own record?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly.
SDE reads from the geometrytype column, which can only have [these values](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z00000052000000), and one value per object.

The only workaround (within the esri realm) is to create views for each geometry column and register sde feature class [(9.3 example).](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/st_geom-270510096.htm)
Now that I look at it this may be [another workaround](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ST_GeomCollFromWKB/006z0000004z000000/).
That is if you want to use wkb as your geometry.

Comment: Storing as WKB would mean no spatial index.  Multiple records, or multiple columns, would allow the shapes to be  indexed.  If the point and poly had to be contained in one object, it isn't hard to create a UDT with two attributes.  Then the attributes could be indexed.